# opencv contrib problem with sift and surf

Tags: python, opencv, sift, surf, opencv-contrib

for the following code!

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
```

i get this error

> AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'

when i install it using conda:
*Requirement already satisfied: opencv-contrib-python in c:\users***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.4.2.16)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in c:\users***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from opencv-contrib-python) (1.18.1)*

but when i run: pip install opencv-contrib-pyt , iget :

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-pyt (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-pyt

i don't undestand if it's already installed or no, when i can't use sift even i have opencv and opencvcontrib

Comment: Try `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Comment: _i don't undestand if it's already installed or no, when i can't use sift even i have opencv and opencvcontrib_ This is likely due to how your environments are setup. Are you sure you're using the correct environment?

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-pyt (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-pyt

Comment: i don't create envs, just the root